# Binding to filtered version of collection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a collection that contains all the items that I want to keep track of.  I want to display 3 different grids, and in each one I want to display a different filtered version of the items.  Is there a way to bind to a filtered version of the main collection without having to maintain 3 separate collections to bind to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use databinding, you must use the entire collection.  I suggest you split the collection, and bind to each.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) instances, each of which gives a different view of the collection.  Note that you'll need to instantiate an appropriate derived type, such as ListCollectionView or CollectionViewSource.

---

Sorry, I just realized you're in WinForms; the above is a WPF class.  You can probably use it anyway if you're willing to include a reference to PresentationFramework (even if you're not using WPF for your application.)

Comment: Are there any issues with adding a reference to PresentationFramework from Winforms?

Comment: I haven't tried using CollectionViews in particular from WinForms, but I've linked to it for hosting WPF Controls inside an ElementHost WinForms Control with no problems.